# Understanding inconsistent ability to RDP to Windows server

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, nat

I have the occasional need to remote into a cloud-hosted Windows Server VM via RDP, but I run into problems in some cases.

Yes, a private VPN to the server is better, but my question here is to understand why straight RDP does not work in some situations.

I temporarily allow access to a custom port (~53000) from my current public IPv4 address through the hosting cloud firewall, and the VM is configured to accept RDP on that port. **This RDP setup works fine in most situations.**

However, I can run into trouble when:

- on corporate guest networks
- on captive portal (?) hotel WiFi
- using a big-name VPN on my client PC

These typically give me a 10. or 172. non-routable address with NAT to access the internet. (And, yes, I do open the port for my public IP, not the non-routable LAN address.) However,  tethered mobile connections with NAT do generally work, as do connections from a home LAN with NAT, so NAT by itself is not the issue.

I check connectivity successfully and simply by testing with `psping.exe` as per the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/troubleshoot/rdp-error-general-troubleshooting). When RDP works, psping is successful like this:

[image]

And when RDP does not work, this is the psping failure (noting those 0.0.0.0's):

[image: Failed ping]

**My questions:**

1. I understand that port 3389 could be blocked by policy on the 3 types of access (corporate/hotel/VPN) just for safety. **Is RDP over a custom port typically identified heuristically and blocked for similar reasons?** (I realize that my ping problems point to it being more general issue, not just RDP, but my question stands.)
2. It seems that my problematic cases could be caused by blocked traffic at NAT, but separate from it being known as RDP traffic. **Do those 0.0.0.0's provide a clue why ping and RDP are failing?** Or are they just a result of the failure?
3. **Should using a general purpose VPN client  work for my scenario?** (e.g. ExpressVPN, NordVPN, etc.) My VPN support gave a simple "that is not a tested case" which is vague and unsatisfying, and perhaps another way to say "no".

Any help to fill in my knowledge here is much appreciated.

Edit: Add Find-NetRoute output for working and a non-working (VPN) case:
[image]

Comment: What does the client's routing table look like in both cases? What's the result of `Find-NetRoute -RemoteAddress 40.██████.141` in both cases?

Comment: I would expect not only port 3389 to be blocked (blacklisting) but in opposite public Wifi often use whitelisting which means all ports are blocked except from some standard ports like 80 443 587 993...

Comment: Not resolved yet, but here are a few things I've learned: (A) The Reset Configuration in the Azure portal does NOT actually change my listening port. (B) The Serial Console in the portal was effective for resetting the listening port. (C) The psping test is only meaningful if RDP is actually listening in that one port. You need to change the RDP port, server firewall, and NSG rules and reboot before testing with psping on another port. (D) Tested RDP on 3 ports (700's, 3389, 53000's). All work fine with consumer NAT; none work with ExpressVPN running. (E) PortQuiz.net:3389 to test outbound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that port 3389 could be blocked by policy on the 3 types of access (corporate/hotel/VPN) just for safety. Is RDP over a custom port typically identified heuristically and blocked for similar reasons? (I realize that my ping problems point to it being more general issue, not just RDP, but my question stands.)

It's uncommonly blocked, but it *may* be blocked to prevent the spread of worms attacking unpatched RDP servers from infected guest laptops (similar to why SMB, MS-RPC, MS-SQL ports are often blocked).

As for custom ports, though, I haven't heard of any cases of using DPI (though that's possible) – a hotel would more likely block the *entire* ephemeral port range as it has very few standard uses (our guest Wi-Fi and student VPN service do so because of people forgetting that their BitTorrent clients are still running in the background).

> Do those 0.0.0.0's provide a clue why ping and RDP are failing? Or are they just a result of the failure?

They're most likely the result of the failure. When psping successfully makes a TCP connection it can call getsockname() (or the Winsock2 equivalent) to retrieve the local address:port that the OS automatically selected for it, but when the connection wasn't successful, the values might not necessarily be filled in.

Test with more tools to be sure, e.g. `Test-Connection -TcpPort` or any other basic TCP client. Try using Wireshark to check what packets actually go out through the VPN interface.

> Should using a general purpose VPN client work for my scenario? (e.g. ExpressVPN, NordVPN, etc.) My VPN support gave a simple "that is not a tested case" which is vague and unsatisfying, and perhaps another way to say "no".

By default yes (assuming you've allowed the VPN-provided public IP address, not the one you saw before connecting). However, the public address will not necessarily remain static throughout the VPN session – many "privacy oriented" VPN providers will [deliberately](https://www.expressvpn.com/support/knowledge-hub/does-expressvpn-offer-static-or-dynamic-ips/) NAT each connection to a different IP from their public address pool, unless you specifically [request](https://nordvpn.com/features/dedicated-ip/) a static IP address as an additional service.

So my guess is simply that your RDP connection no longer matches the firewall rule you've set up, either because the external NAT address changed after some amount of time, or because a different NAT address is used for a different destination IP.

(I wouldn't call those "general purpose VPN clients", quite the opposite – they have a specific purpose of connecting to just that *one* VPN service, and are built to use that one service's protocol and APIs.)

Comment: Thank you! A couple of follow-ups: It seems I should try a lower port number. Any advice on how low to go? I'm on Windows at both ends, so the breakpoints seem to be 49152, 5000, and 1024. Maybe a likely-whitelisted and registered (but unused) port?  With respect to specific-purpose VPN clients, I was monitoring my public IP via browser and Ctrl-F5 and have never seen it change during my session. Is that a reliable way to check?

Comment: It's more about what the network's operator considers "ephemeral range that's not used for any services" and not about what the OS does. I'd try regular 3389 since you're using IP filtering anyway, but other than that try various ports below 1024.

Comment: NordVPN explicitly says they do not support RDP due to port blocking and there are no workarounds: https://nordvpn.com/blog/vpn-vs-rdp  Time to do it the right way with my own private VPN to the server!

Comment: For anyone who got this far, what you will need in Azure is a  [Point to Site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about)  There are plenty of YouTube walk-through videos (once you know what you are looking for).